# Chromium with USB headset microphone

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, chromium, microphone

I've recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Thinkpad T495 and started using my USB headset (It has a jack pin, but with a jack-to-USB converter) in a USB hub.

It works fine in Firefox, Audacity and other applications, but the sound input is not working in any chromium-based app. Neither in Chrome or Chromium Web Browser, nor in Slack desktop app.

I've tried

- configuring ALSA in `alsamixer`
- `pavucontrol`
- set the default sound card in `~/.asoundrc`
- set the default source and remapping in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`
- adding slack to apparmor complain
- reinstall slack from snap, and two different .deb file (even `apt upgrade slack-desktop`)
- uninstall completely chrome and chromium, then install it from snap and uninstall again and install from .deb
- checking `~/.config/Slack/logs` for anything related to sound or alsa
- disabling other soundcards
- disabling mic boosts

If I open a chromium app (slack desktop app, slack in chrome, google meets in chrome) and `pavucontrol`, then on the "Recording" tab the volume meter indicates input from the source as I speak, but the application's (again slack or chrome) indicator is at constant zero.

Slack's and Chrome's sound test gives "Success" for both speaker and microphone, and I can hear the test sounds, but the microphone seems mute.

I checked the `alsamixer` and `pacmd list-source-outputs`, and those show the microphone, and it isn't muted, and the volume level is at 100%.

I've tried to plug the headset into a jack slot, but that just didn't work at all in any applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing `pavucontrol`, `pulseaudio` and even `alsa`, then simply put my headphone into a jack input, then reinstalling the removed packages. I tried without `pavucontrol`, but it was neccessary to make it work from Chrome.

Since these reinstalls my microphone works fine in Slack and in anything Chromium related softwares. I think the problem could be that the USB soundcard isn't preferred in some components.